# 1-form integration

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms, curves

Let $\alpha:[-1,1]\rightarrow R^2$ be the curve segment given by $\alpha=(t,t^2)$.

If $\phi=v^2du+2uvdv$, (the fist component of $R^2$ is $u$ and the second one is $v$)

I have

$$\int_\alpha \phi=\int_{[-1,1]}\phi(\alpha'(t))dt=\int_{-1}^1(4t^2*0+2*1*2t*2)dt=4t^2|^1_{-1}=0$$

and also from $\phi=d(uv^2)$,

$$\int_\alpha \phi=\int_\alpha d(uv^2)=\int_{-1}^1d(t^3)=1+1=2$$

I'm pretty sure that one of them is wrong(or both are. hope not). Help me. Thanks.

Comment: $\phi(\alpha(t))$, not $\phi(\alpha'(t))\,dt$. And $\phi(\alpha(t)) = (t^2)^2\,dt + 2t(t^2)\,d(t^2) = t^4\,dt + 4t^4\,dt = 5t^4\,dt$.

Comment: @DanielFischer My Diff. Geometry book (O'neil, p.175) states the latter. I'm more confused now

Comment: and it's still 0. is my second computation wrong?

Comment: yes, note that $uv^2$ is equal to $t^5$ in $\alpha$, which is consistent with @DanielFischer's comment

Comment: As John C said, in terms of $t$, you'd get $d(t^5)$. You can also evaluate $\int_{(-1,1)}^{(1,1)} d(uv^2) = 1\cdot 1^2 - (-1)\cdot 1^2$.

Comment: Ahh, $t^5$. Thanks. But then why my text book says the 1-form integration is $\int_{[a,b]} \phi(\alpha'(t))dt$? it looks valid in a sense that it uses velocity.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783949/defining-the-integral-of-differential-1-forms?rq=1 also states the same definition. anyone knows why this definition doesn't work?

Comment: It should be $\int_{[a,b]} \phi_{\alpha(t)} (\alpha'(t))dt$. The integrand is the form $\phi$ evaluated at the point $(u,v) = \alpha(t)$, and then that covector is applied to the vector $\alpha'(t)$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Abuse of notation. (What I wrote was abuse of notation too, but a different one.) What it really should be is $$\int_{-1}^1 \phi(\alpha(t))(T_t\alpha(\partial/\partial t))\,dt.$$ You evaluate the $1$-form $\phi$ at the point $\alpha(t)$, which gives you a linear form on the tangent space at the point $\alpha(t)$. You then apply that linear form to $T_t\alpha(\partial/\partial t)$, which is the image of the tangent vector $\partial/\partial t$ under the tangent map of $\alpha$ (the differential of $\alpha$) to get a value.

Comment: Since that is quite cumbersome, one writes $\alpha'(t)$ for $T_t\alpha(\partial/\partial t)$. So with that, you'd get $$\int_{-1}^1 \phi(\alpha(t))(\alpha'(t))\,dt.$$ Now since $\alpha'(t) \in T_{\alpha(t)}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $\phi(p)(\alpha'(t))$ is well-formed only for $p = \alpha(t)$, hence one can omit that argument, there's only one sensible interpretation. Unfortunately, when you're working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where you have a canonical identification between the tangent spaces and $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is easy to mistake things.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. now I get what you mean. so $\phi$ is evaluated at $\alpha(t)$, not $\alpha'(t)$. But then I have one problem: in the proof of $$\int_{\alpha} df=f(q)-f(p)$$where $f$ is a function on surface $M$, and $p$, $q$ are the start and end point of $\alpha$ respectively, By Definition$$\int_\alpha df=\int_a^b df(\alpha')dt$$But $$df(\alpha')=\alpha'[f]=\frac{d}{dt}(f(\alpha))$$Hence, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, it is proved. And here, I think $\alpha'$ is used as a variable of 1-form $df$.

Comment: AHHHHHHHH NOW I REALLY GET IT. at $\alpha(t)$, in direction $\alpha'(t)$. Thank you guys. I appreciate.

Comment: $\phi$ is evaluated at $\alpha(t)$ so that you get something which you can apply to $\alpha'(t)$. Using Jack Lee's nicer notation, we have $df_{\alpha(t)}(\alpha'(t))$ as the integrand. And that is just $(f\circ\alpha)'(t)$. The two play fundamentally different roles. $\phi$ is a section in the cotangent bundle of the manifold, so $\phi_p \in T^\ast_pM = L(T_pM,\mathbb{R})$. Evaluating the $1$-form at a point gives you the linear form you can apply to a tangent vector - that tangent vector is $\alpha'(t)$ here.